# Net.Pkcs11 - Native Dll

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm using Net.Pkcs11 in orther to work with BIT4ID miniLector EVO smartcard.

Net.Pkcs11 requires the native dll, usually provided with smartcard driver, however I don't know which dll I need, neither if that dll has been provided with the smartcard driver.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I answer to my question by myself.

I've found the dll that incoming with smartcard driver.

Its name is FNMT_P11.dll and Net.Pkcs11 works properly.